# Python Importing package at same level but different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

python version:3.9.6

I cannot seem to get this to work I know there are a million posts that are the same as this but the solutions never seem to work for me. I've run into this before and always end up just restructuring the folders to include all files in one path which is obviously not ideal. So here I am once again asking you guys for help.

My folder structure is as follows

```
|project
    |my_service
        -my_service.py
    |tests
        - tests.py
```

I'm trying to get the function `get_num_back` from `my_service.py` and import it into `tests.py`.

I've tried relative imports `from ..my_service.my_service import get_num_back` this doesn't work because from what I've read I cannot hit the root folder.

I've then tried absolute import `from my_service.my_service import get_num_back` which is the answer I see works for everyone else but it doesn't seem to work for me. I've then tried `from project import my_service` as well as from project.my_service import my_service. as far as I understand with my python version I do not need `__init__.py` but I've also tried it with that as well.
the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

Please settle this for me once and for all!

Comment: Almost all of these posts boil down to "How are you running your program?". Your current working directory matters.

Comment: I'm trying to run the pytest package to learn unit testing and i'm running it from the project/test path

Comment: `from my_service.my_service import get_num_back` should work if you run pytest from `project` directory

Comment: To add onto that, if you want to run it without `pytest`, run `python -m tests.tests` from the `project` folder.

Comment: Awesome thank you all for your help. I did not realize from where I ran my script mattered. Thank you x 10000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Always* run `py.test` from your `project` directory.

Because from that directory it can actually find `my_service`.

---

For more information, read up on relative imports in the language reference documentation.

Comment: Thank you, and everyone else. This is what worked. I was not aware that from where you ran the script mattered on imports.

Comment: To be honest, I think basically *everybody* struggles with this in the beginning.